# How to create a comment box and comment display feature in flask?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, flask, web

Hi I am currently trying to create a comment box feature in flask. The problem I am facing is that when I click on the submit button, nothing happens. I want the user to be able to see the message they wrote along with their username below the comment box.

Here is my code:
python file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3 

conn = sqlite3.connect('comments.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, comment TEXT)''')
conn.commit()

@app.route('/add_comment', methods=['POST'])
def add_comment():
    name = request.form['name']
    comment = request.form['comment']
    c.execute("INSERT INTO comments (name, comment) VALUES (?, ?)", (name, comment))
    conn.commit()
    return render_template('comment.html', name=name, comment=comment) 

@app.route('/')
def view_comments():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC")
    comments = c.fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', comments=comments)
```

javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#comment-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ url_for('add_comment') }}",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#comments").append(data);
        $("#name").val('');
        $("#comment").val('');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

html file:

```
<form id="comment-form" action="{{ url_for('add_comment') }}" method="post">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="comments">
  {% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="comment">
      <p><strong>{{ comment[1] }}:</strong> {{ comment[2] }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning a response from the post method (`add_comment`), you can skip AJAX use. Here is an example to load the comments on form submission.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
conn = sqlite3.connect('comments.db', check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, comment TEXT)''')
conn.commit()


@app.route('/add_comment', methods=['POST'])
def add_comment():
    name = request.form['name']
    comment = request.form['comment']
    c.execute("INSERT INTO comments (name, comment) VALUES (?, ?)", (name, comment))
    conn.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("view_comments"))


@app.route('/')
def view_comments():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC")
    comments = c.fetchall()
    return render_template('comment.html', comments=comments)
```

`templates/comment.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Comments Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="comment-form" action="{{ url_for('add_comment') }}" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="comments">
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="comment">
        <p><strong>{{ comment[1] }}:</strong> {{ comment[2] }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: example]

Comment: unfortunetly i'm having the same problem :/ i have this error pop up on my ide: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2023 13:43:47] "POST /%7B%7B%20url_for('add_comment')%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: how would i be able to fix that? ^^

Comment: @intothedata . I tried the code and it's working. you need to update flask code